# how to escape special and non-english characters on key press?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i want to ignore all **special character** but "-" and **non-english characters** on key press in jquery. Actually this input is used to check domain availability. like;

www.***_*__*_*__*_*_**.com | for and end extensions are already provided for user. they won't enter those parts.

can you help?

Comment: i know i could but i need the rule, that's the problem.

Comment: You need to learn about IDN.

Comment: so `www.foo-äöü.com` would be ok, but `www.foo-☃.com` not.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need the rule"?

Comment: if im not mistaken non-english characters are allowed in domain names

Comment: @RecepŞimşek if you know you need a rule/expression, what have you tried???

Comment: @patrick yea but i don't need those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a onChange event, since users can also paste something into the field.

To check if the string is a valid url, use this pattern

```
var urlPattern = /(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?/
```